# How to read in multiple files separately from multiple directories in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, directory

I have x directories which are Star_{v} with v=0 to x. 
I have 2 csv files in each directory, one with the word "epoch", one without.
If one of the csv files has the word "epoch" in it needs to be sent through one set of code, else through another. 
I think dictionaries are probably the way to go but this section of the code is a bit of a wrong mess

```
directory_dict={}

for var in range(0, len(subdirectory)):
#var refers to the number by which the subdirectories are labelled by Star_0, Star_1 etc. 

    directory_dict['Star_{v}'.format(v=var)]=directory\\Star_{var}
    #directory_dict['Star_0'], directory_dict['Star_1'] etc.

    read_csv(f) for f in os.listdir('directory_dict[Star_{var}') if f.endswith(".csv")
    #reads in all the files in the directories(star{v}) ending in csv.
    if 'epoch' in open(read_csv[0]).read():
    #if the word epoch is in the csv file then it is 
        directory_dict[Star_{var}][read] = csv.reader(read_csv[0])
        directory_dict[Star_{var}][read1] = csv.reader(read_csv[1])
    else:
        directory_dict[Star_{var}][read] = csv.reader(read_csv[1])
        directory_dict[Star_{var}][read1] = csv.reader(read_csv[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with csvs, you should use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), and for your particular case, you can use a dictreader and parse the headers to check for the column you're looking for

```
import csv
import os

directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # change this to your directory
csv_list = [os.path.join(directory, c) for c in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.splitext(c) == 'csv']

def parse_csv_file():
  " open CSV and check the headers "
  for c in csv_list:
    with open(c, mode='r') as open_csv:
     reader = csv.DictReader(open_csv)
     if 'epoch' in reader.fieldnames:
       # do whatever you want here
     else:
       # do whatever else
```

then you can extract it from the DictReader's CSV header and do whatever you want

Also your python looks invalid